# Exchanging US Dollars for Indian Rupees

Tags: united-states, india, foreign-exchange

I am planning to visit the USA next month for approximately 6 months. My questions are as follows:

- How do I convert USD to INR when I want to transfer funds back to India?
- Do I have to create new bank account?
- Are there any taxes I need to pay in the USA?
- What deductions are there?
- If we are going to the USA and getting paid in USD as salary, how is USD converted into INR?
- If I have 10000 INR in USA and I want to convert to USD, what would the exchange house do with the Rupees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking quite a few questions here;

1. If you have Rs 10000, its better you get it converted in India before you leave. Most Banks and Exchange houses like Western Union would take Rupees and Give you USD. What do they do with USD, there are other who give them USD and need Rupees. They make a spread in this process.
2. If you are getting a salary in USD in US, whenever you want to transfer money to India, the Banks or Remittance services like Western Union would take USD from your US Account and Transfter equivalent Money into your Bank Account in India in Rupees. They will tell the exchange rate applicable.
3. Depending on why visa type & the duration you are going, your company should be able to tell you your tax liabilities in the US. Read similar questions here to get a general idea.

Comment: indians are going more and more to USA. but americans are coming to india was very very less. what am asking is if take example i am going to buy some goods in retail shop. i gave money to him and get goods. he using money to buying the goods. likewise process is going.